Early 2000s comedy with man being interrogated
Trying to find a movie that I can only remember one scene. The main person is being questioned about being assaulted and he lies and describes the person as being "black but looks white or white and looks black, with red hair and a gold tooth" he gets a call a little later and the police actually find a guy that matches the description....

You are looking for "A Guy Thing", if my memory is correct. Oh! You can also confirm at this review on amazon where the scene in question is explicitly mentioned:

A moment I particularly like is when Paul Coleman (Jason Lee) is beaten up by Ray and thrown into a dumpster. His fiancee Karen (Selma Blair) happens along. Of course, being a guy trying to salvage some pride, he fabricates a story that he was brave despite being mugged. So when the police show up, his description of the perpetrator gets more & more bizarre. "What was his race?" the officer asks. Lee looks puzzled. "Was he black or white?" "A little of both." "And he had red hair, in dreadlocks, with a gold tooth, and a tattoo of barbed wire around his neck." Paul of course thinks that no one will match that description only to wind up at a line-up where Hansberry played by Victor Varnado stands there, part black, part white, red hair, dreadlocks, with a gold tooth & a tattoo of barbed wire around his neck. "Oh, it's not him!" Lee yells. It's stupid; but it's hilarious.


For some reason the movie Johnny English is popping into my head but I can't find anything to support my thought.  I am going to try and find something.

This: "The power to the room is cut, and English knocks out the chief of security, before pretending to fight a criminal (later described by English as having orange frizzy hair, two teeth, two "banana shaped" scars, a broken nose and an eye patch)"  and this: "There is also a short scene in the credits showing Lorna landing in a swimming pool as the orange haired criminal described earlier by English lowers his newspaper." are what you're looking for
